# Duplicate and rename project from Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, repository, project

I'm working on a project in a large repository and it's been decided that it has reached the point where I'm going to split it, and keep one project in it's current state and continue modifying the functionality in the other.

What I did:

- Copied project folder.
- Pasted it within same git parent folder on my pc
- Renamed solution + project

I'm relatively new to git so this may be a non-issue, but the new renamed project still has red ticks where I made changes. It's still associated with the git. What I would more like is basically this entire project to be a red tick and add it to the repository as an extra. (Git repo will now contain two project (Unmodified and modified).

The reference concerns me as it makes me wonder if when I push changes to Git my project is somehow still related somehow and I'll lose my original when I make modifications to my clone.

If that makes sense.....Is there a way of disassociating a solution from the Git repo and readding it as if the whole thing is a new, external project? Kind of like if my mate just gave me a random solution and I wanted to add it to the repo...

Thanks in advance
JK

Comment: https://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I may be mistaken but isn't that post talking about creating a new repository? I am wanting to use the same repository we use now. It currently contains 5 solutions and I want to duplicate one solution and have it's copy stand alone as a sixth solution, but still within the same git repo. So the original solution will remain unchanged whilst I continue working on the new 6th solution.

Comment: Sorry, I did´nt read it carefully enough. Sounds like what you are looking for are branches.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj190809.aspx

Comment: Maybe. So the git repo is currently under one branch called Master. the repo contains two folders, which contain 1 and 4 solutions recpectively. As I say I really am new to Git, my personal projects never required it. I am not the original creator of the repository so far I have just worked with pushing, pulling and syncing as my modifications have been to existing projects, not creating new ones.

Comment: See my answer for a explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach to this is by using branches. In GIT branches are not actually different folders within a project (unlike SVN) but rather snapshots of the state of the repository.

I´m going to list the console commands to achieve this since its easier to explain what is actually going on. [Visual studio instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj190809.aspx).

You can split off a legacy branch, which can be maintained separately from your master branch.

```
git branch legacy
```

This creates a separate branch from the current commit (you can name it whatever you want). You can visit the branch by:

```
git checkout legacy
```

Or the shorthand `git checkout -b legacy` to create and switch branch. You can then use merges for example to apply fixes from your master branch to the legacy branch.

I really recommend the free [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and actually using git from the command line first as gives you a proper understanding of how the tool actually works rather that just what buttons to push.

Comment: Thankyou for the book recommendation and the advice. I'll read more around it before implementing it. The problem with not understanding an area much is you don't know how to phrase questions, and you also don't know if the answer is precisely what you want or not! Thanks for the help

Comment: How do I do that? I attempted to upvote it but I need 15 reputation before I can do that.